# Language fallback configure

Tags: language-fallback

In my local sitecore, I am implementing language fallback in Multisite Manager (*I have multiple sites in an instance*). I have added     `enableItemLanguageFallback` attribute for one site node in multisite Manager.
I am able to achieve fallback successfully for that particular site. I haven't changed anything on `Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config` file.

However, when I implemented same for higher environment, i am not able to achieve above.

My question is, whether enabling fallback in `Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config` is required or not?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enable language fallback. Yes, below configuration needs to be set.

It can be set in Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config or on `<site>` nodes in Sitecore.config. Both are same.

But its recommended using patch files for any modifications.

```
<sites>
  <site name="shell">
    <patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
  </site>
  <site name="website">
    <patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
  </site>
</sites>
```

if you have site 2 you need to add:

```
<site name="site2">
    <patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
  </site>
```

Here is the official sitecore documentation on language-fallback: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/language_fallback/language_fallback

Comment: Thanks Dheeraj. But, in my local instance, i achieved the same without any change on `Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config`. Only an entry of `enableItemLanguageFallback` to `true` worked for me.

Comment: Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config is a patch file which just sets enableItemLanguageFallback in <site> node.